# What is the purpose of config\Software.log

Tags: windows

What is the purpose of:

C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\Software.log

How to open it.

Answer (score 9):

The file contains the journal of the [HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software hive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724877%28VS.85%29.aspx).  If the machine crashes while in the middle of updating a registry key in that hive, the .log file is used to recover the registry. I would recommend not messing with the file unless you know what you are doing.

Comment: I have a lot of disk writes to this file in my Exchange2013 VM... do you think this is necessary?

Comment: I'm not current on Windows, but having said that, I would be very surprised if normal system activity included a lot of writes to that log. Do you know the disk is good (if the drive is seeing errors, you can see a lot of writes)? Do you know what process is issuing the writes?

Answer (score 2):

It is part of your Registry, you cannot open it directly

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/256986