# Why continous I/O to c:\windows\system32\config\SOFTWARE.LOG1

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008-r2, linux-kvm

Referring to for the original question, [What is the purpose of config\Software.log](https://superuser.com/questions/131256/what-is-the-purpose-of-config-software-log) but my question is rather **WHY** the continuous writing to that file. I have 6x Windows 2008R2 SP1 VMs, and they consume a constant 1 to 3MByte/sec writing, and looking at the performance monitor, that file and it's sibling c:\windows\system32\config\SOFTWARE.LOG I see using each about 2Kbyte/sec being written to it.

Okay, I'm a Un*x guy, so that is the reason I'm asking why or where I could track what might be the reason for this constant I/O.

**EDIT:** It's being written to by
Image: System
PID: 4 (As just about anything "System" appears to have that PID number on this instance)

Comment: You could try and use Process Monitor to find out which process is writing to the registry.

Comment: The values and information I saw, came from Resource Monitor (from Task Manager).
@DanielB Where do I get the Process Monitor ?

Comment: google Windows Process Monitor -> #1 https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/processmonitor.aspx and download (then run) or 'run ... from Live'

Answer (score -1):

Possibly defrag/shrink (I did a partition shrink that seems to have triggered this crap - at first via defrag.exe)

Comment: I agree with your assessment of Microsoft's software quality but that commentary doesn't belong in this answer.